# Angular2 assign style dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to assign style in a `th` dynamically in Angular 2.

I tried the following:

```
<th [ngStyle]="{'width:25%': col.field != 'email'}"
    *ngFor="let col of cols"
    [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
        {{col.header}}
</th>
```

But the above fails.

How should I assign the style property?

Answer (score 2):

You have done it incorrectly. The correct way to do it is:

```
<th [ngStyle]="{'width': col.field != 'email' ? '25%': auto}"
        *ngFor="let col of cols"
        [pSortableColumn]="col.field"
>
  {{col.header}}
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `[ngStyle]` directive. It does not work like the `[ngClass]` directive, (adding or removing a css class based on condition). It rather assigns a certain style to the elements `CSSStyleDeclaration` property, so you should manage dynamic styles maually, like this, in your example:

```
<th *ngFor ="let col of cols" [ngStyle]="{'width': col.field != 'email' ? '25%': 'auto'}"> // etc
```

As you seem, I used ternary operator to  assign a style dynamically. You can also do this:

```
<th *ngFor ="let col of cols" [style.width]="col.field != 'email' ? '25%': 'auto'"> // etc
```

Which is obviously shorter. And, by the way, `*ngFor` as a property should come before you use the iteration variable among other attributes/directives on the same element (`*ngFor` and only then `[ngStyle]`, as you use the `col` variable declared in `*ngFor` inside the `[ngStyle]` directive, not the other way round)